# How to display user avatar next to post? (php,mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I have two tables in my database one is called **Users** and the other is **News**
I made it that users can add News Posts to the site, but I couldn't display user's image next to his post

this is my code right now

```
<?php
$News = "";
$user_id = "";


$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$sqlCommand3 = "SELECT * FROM Users"; 

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$query3 = mysql_query($sqlCommand3) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
$News .= "";
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) ){


    $News .= "<a href=\"news?id=".$row['id']."\"><div class=\"news-post\"> <img src=\".$row2['author_avatar']."\"><p>".$row['author']."</p>  <h2>".$row['title']."</h2></div>  </a>";

        } // close while

} else {
$News = "No News!";
}

?>
```

I want where is says $row2['author_avatar'] to echo the image from the users table

Comment: I'd suggest tweaking your SQL - can you do it in a single query, joining `news` on `users`? That will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @andrewsi two tables in one query? is that even possible?

Comment: It's very possible: have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp to get you started.

Comment: @andrewsi w3school ? no way ?

Comment: @samitha - their PHP code isn't great, but their SQL tutorials aren't too bad. Do you have a suggestion for a better site for SQL tutorials? I get a bit lost when it's not on php.net :D

Answer (score 0):

You missed out a speech mark (") just before $row2['author_avatar'].

```
<?php
$News = "";
$user_id = "";


$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$sqlCommand3 = "SELECT * FROM Users"; 

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$query3 = mysql_query($sqlCommand3) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
$News .= "";
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) ){


    $News .= "<a href=\"news?id=".$row['id']."\"><div class=\"news-post\"> <img src="\".$row2['author_avatar']."\"><p>".$row['author']."</p>  <h2>".$row['title']."</h2></div>  </a>";

        } // close while

} else {
$News = "No News!";
}

?>
```

You should look up INNER JOIN rather than having two SQL queries as mentioned by andrewsi. Here's a good tutorial on how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BfofgkrI3Y.